# Conflict in the fact that object is a ref type

Tags: c#, object, ref

I've read about ref and value types in c# but don't know in the following example why `y = 10` although `x` and `y` are reference types?

```
object x = 10;
object y = x;
x = 20;
Console.WriteLine(y); //why y = 10 although x and y are reference types?
```

And if you convince me of the reason, how could I change the object that is referenced by both x and y?

Comment: Reference and value doesn't matter here. At all. You reassigned x. That will not effect y in this sample no matter what type of type it is.

Comment: Use a string. Use an int. Use your own custom class Foo. They all behave the same.

Comment: What would you expect y to be? Why?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram you make it clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your answers and this example may make the thing clearer.

```
class Complex
{
    public int real;
    public int imag;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Complex c1 = new Complex();
    Complex c2 = new Complex();
    c2.real = 100;
    c2.imag = 100;

    object x = c1;
    object y = x;

    ((Complex)x).imag = 50; //y here is changed

    x = c2; //y here isn't changed because this line makes x is now pointing on sth else which doesn't matter with the object referenced by y

}
```

Comment: There you go, that's a solid understanding of reassignment of a variable *versus* modifying properties of an object referenced by variables.

Answer (score 3):

Let's ignore the `object` type for a moment. When you make an initialization like that

```
SomeType y = x;
```

`y` becomes an *alias* to `x` if `SomeType` is a reference type `class`, or it becomes a *copy* of `x` if `SomeType` is a value type `struct`.

The situation when it becomes visible is when `SomeType` is *mutable*. In situations with reference types changing the content of the object referenced through `x` would also change `y`, because it's the same object. If it is a copy, however, changing `x` has no effect on the `y`.

Since your code uses objects of boxed immutable type wrapping integer primitives, this assignment

```
x = 20;
```

makes variable `x` refer to an entirely different immutable object. The value of `y` remains unchanged.

Comment: yes, the idea is in the immutability of the type of the referenced object.
And assigning is making the reference refers to another location.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: but how int is immutable although I can make: int i = 5; then i = 10; and this happens in the same memory location?

Comment: @user2036214 `int`'s object wrapper class `System.Int32` is immutable. `int` is a primitive, so it's definitely mutable. When you assign an integer constant to `object`, C# compiler automatically wraps the value in a `System.Int32` object.

Comment: @user2036214, immutability, mutability, structs, classes, none of that has any relevance here, to be honest. This is simple reassignment, and it behaves the same for any type that x happens to be. Those terms are useful to understand *in general*, but the point of your x and y here is much simpler. It's just reassignment, no need to get lost in the weeds with the other terms being bandied about.

Answer (score 3):

```
object x = 10;
object y = x;
```

After that `x` and `y` reference to same object:

```
x, y -> 10
```

But when you let `x = 20`:

```
x -> 20
y -> 10
```

You can wrap value with class:

```
class Ref<T>
{
    public T Value;

    public static implicit operator T(Ref<T> x)
    {
        return x.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Ref<T>(T x)
    {
        return new Ref<T>() { Value = x };
    }
}
```

And then:

```
Ref<int> x = 10;
Ref<int> y = x;

// x, y -> Ref -> 10

x.Value = 20;

// x, y -> Ref -> 20

Console.WriteLine(y); // y is 20 (or rather y.Value is 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement -

```
Object x = 10
```

has a special name and it is called **Boxing**. That is wrapping a value type inside a reference type. You might be thinking that this should create a reference. Yes you are right. But this also means a new object is created - as mentioned in the doc -

> When a value type is boxed, a new object must be allocated and constructed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Now when you do -

```
object y = x;
```

Y and X are same object here pointing to same memory location. This far is okay. But the next statement -

```
x = 20;
```

is causing the exception. You see, this statement is another boxing and as boxing creates new instances, this is creating another new object with value 20 and putting/referring that with X.

So, Y is pointing to the last memory location where X is pointing to a new memory location.

You can understand why by visiting the link I mentioned above.

**And if you convince me of the reason, how could I change the object that is referenced by both x and y?** => You can't! Because C# does not support explicit pointers and you are using value types.

However if X and Y were reference types (i.e. `Class` objects) then you could have done that.